Could not set unknown property 'classifier' for task ':expo-av:androidSourcesJar' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar
ERROR:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':expo-av'.
> Could not set unknown property 'classifier' for task ':expo-av:androidSourcesJar' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

I'm currently using nx monorepo and pnpm with these i install expo-av i get the above error in my root node_modules
"expo-av": "~14.0.7",

this is how my expo-av is and in my project's node_modules i have the expo-av like
"expo-av": "~14.0.7",

first i have tried like
"expo-av": "*",

which is also not worked as i expected, kindly help me with this
